# Nautilus is slowed on after dnf upgrade

Tags: fedora, gnome, nautilus

I'm using Fedora 29 gnome and currently I have nautilus-3.30.5-1.fc29.x86_64.

It's very laggy right now. It opens folder very slowly, and I can see loading text bottom right.

**What I've tried so far**

I've removed ~/.cache/tracker

I've downgraded nautilus to nautilus-3.30.2-1.fc29.x86_64, issue continues.

**After killall nautilus and nautilus**

It's my output, there are more and more and still producing.

```
(nautilus:4258): Gtk-WARNING **: 17:34:12.268: Duplicate child name in GtkStack: ios

(nautilus:4258): Gtk-WARNING **: 17:34:12.269: Duplicate child name in GtkStack: Runner.xcworkspace

(nautilus:4258): Gtk-WARNING **: 17:34:12.270: Duplicate child name in GtkStack: Runner.xcodeproj

(nautilus:4258): Gtk-WARNING **: 17:34:12.271: Duplicate child name in GtkStack: Runner

(nautilus:4258): Gtk-WARNING **: 17:34:12.272: Duplicate child name in GtkStack: Flutter

(nautilus:4258): Gtk-WARNING **: 17:34:12.273: Duplicate child name in GtkStack: android

(nautilus:4258): Gtk-WARNING **: 17:34:12.274: Duplicate child name in GtkStack: app

(nautilus:4258): Gtk-WARNING **: 17:34:12.275: Duplicate child name in GtkStack: test

(nautilus:4258): Gtk-WARNING **: 17:34:12.276: Duplicate child name in GtkStack: lib

(nautilus:4258): Gtk-WARNING **: 17:34:12.277: Duplicate child name in GtkStack: ios

(nautilus:4258): Gtk-WARNING **: 17:34:12.277: Duplicate child name in GtkStack: Runner.xcworkspace

(nautilus:4258): Gtk-WARNING **: 17:34:12.278: Duplicate child name in GtkStack: Runner.xcodeproj

(nautilus:4258): Gtk-WARNING **: 17:34:12.278: Duplicate child name in GtkStack: Runner

(nautilus:4258): Gtk-WARNING **: 17:34:12.279: Duplicate child name in GtkStack: Flutter

(nautilus:4258): Gtk-WARNING **: 17:34:12.280: Duplicate child name in GtkStack: android

(nautilus:4258): Gtk-WARNING **: 17:34:12.281: Duplicate child name in GtkStack: app

(nautilus:4258): Gtk-WARNING **: 17:34:12.540: Duplicate child name in GtkStack: test

(nautilus:4258): Gtk-WARNING **: 17:34:12.541: Duplicate child name in GtkStack: unit

(nautilus:4258): Gtk-WARNING **: 17:34:12.541: Duplicate child name in GtkStack: integration

(nautilus:4258): Gtk-WARNING **: 17:34:12.542: Duplicate child name in GtkStack: lib

(nautilus:4258): Gtk-WARNING **: 17:34:12.543: Duplicate child name in GtkStack: models

(nautilus:4258): Gtk-WARNING **: 17:34:12.544: Duplicate child name in GtkStack: mocks

(nautilus:4258): Gtk-WARNING **: 17:34:12.545: Duplicate child name in GtkStack: components

(nautilus:4258): Gtk-WARNING **: 17:34:12.545: Duplicate child name in GtkStack: ios

(nautilus:4258): Gtk-WARNING **: 17:34:12.546: Duplicate child name in GtkStack: Runner.xcworkspace

(nautilus:4258): Gtk-WARNING **: 17:34:12.546: Duplicate child name in GtkStack: Runner.xcodeproj

(nautilus:4258): Gtk-WARNING **: 17:34:12.547: Duplicate child name in GtkStack: Runner

(nautilus:4258): Gtk-WARNING **: 17:34:12.548: Duplicate child name in GtkStack: Flutter

(nautilus:4258): Gtk-WARNING **: 17:34:12.548: Duplicate child name in GtkStack: assets
```

They are related to my Flutter projects on my IdeaProjects folder.

**Solution**
I thought the problem was related to IdeaProjects folder, rudib  informed me that problem is related to my ~/Templates folder.

I had a github repo on my ~/Templates folder which contains many flutter projects in its subfolders. I've deleted that and it solved my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an temporary fix, I would recommend downgrading `nautilus` and [report the bug to the developers](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/nautilus/issues), if it's not reported yet.

```
dnf downgrade nautilus
```

To further debug this issue, run:

```
killall nautilus
nautilus
```

in the terminal. This should provide additional information.

Further investigation pointed to the `~/Templates` folder.
There were some unwanted/duplicate Entries that caused this issue. Removing those should fix the issue. Altough this it not the standard "use-case" I would still consdider it a "bug" worth reporting.

Comment: It's actually downgraded to nautilus-3.30.2-1.fc29.x86_64 but the issue still continues. Is there anything that can cause it?

Comment: I see, it's not the right answer then. I'm running the same version without that issue. Maybe try running it in the terminal `killall nautilus` and then `nautilus`. And post the output.

Comment: Wow, the output is bunch of
`(nautilus:4258): Gtk-WARNING **: 17:33:17.470: Duplicate child name in GtkStack: app
` warnings.

 And it is producing more and more. The errors related to my flutter files, such as lib, models, ios, android, mocks, test. I have many Flutter projects on my IdeaProjects folder(intellij idea)

Comment: Just as a reference, I don't have any warnings when launching nautilus. So that should be part of your problem-

Comment: I have many flutter-android projects with the same file names and file structures. Correct me if I'm wrong but just because I have multiple lib, android, test folders on my laptop, nautilus is producing thousands lines of `Duplicate child name` error?

Comment: I'm not sure yet. Do you have `IntelliJ` running with those window titles or something like that? Could you close everything and try running it again? Or are you using some kind of plugin in nautilus?

Comment: I've done my tests after reboot, there wasn't any app that I'm running.